# Spresenseのサンプルコード "Signal Processing/LowPassSound"を実行しても正常に動作せず、mptask_exec() failure. -12と表示される。

Tags: spresense, arduino

Spresense Reference Board v2.0.1(Spresense Arduino Library v2.0.1)のスケッチ例`Signal Processing/LowPassSound`を実行し、シリアルモニタを開くと以下のようなログが表示され、スピーカーからノイズが再生されました。正常に動作されるためにはどのような処理が必要なのでしょうか？つい先日触り始めた機器のため右も左も分からず、困り果てています…もう一つの開発環境であるIDEバージョンで解決な場合は、ご案内をいただけると助かります。

以下の調査を通してメモリ不足を疑っておりますが、対処の方法が思いつきません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

---

### 環境

windows10 Pro
Arduino IDE 1.8.13
Spresense Reference Board v2.0.1
**ボード設定**
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### 1.サンプルコードをそのまま実行した場合

[公式ドキュメント](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/arduino_tutorials_ja.html#_highpasssound_lowpasssound)を参考にDSPライブラリをSDカードにインストールした後、サンプルコードを実行した。
以下のログが表示された。Insufficient buffer areaとあるので、メモリ不足を疑い、２を実行した。

```
initialization MediaRecorder, MediaPlayer and OutputMixer
recorder init
player init
recorder start
player start
WARNING: Insufficient buffer area.
Error! 8 ,d04d8b0 , 1536
WARNING: Insufficient buffer area.
.
.
.同様の表示
.
Error! 8 ,d04d8b0 , 1536
WARNING: Insufficient buffer area.
```

### 2.サンプリングレートを落とした場合

再生/録音のサンプリングレートを48kHz->16kHzにし、さらにメモリの使用容量を調べるコードをmaincore,subcore1に挿入し実行した。しかしスピーカーから音すら出なかった。
subcore1とmaincoreが起動した時点で`Free: 128 [KB]`となり、ヒープ領域がほとんど存在していない上に、

```
mptask_exec() failure. -12
    Attention: module[11][0] attention id[2]/code[18] (components/decoder/decoder_component.cpp L593)
```

とあり、おそらくDSPモジュールを読み込めなかったことが想定できる。とにかくメモリ不足が原因に見えたが、対処の方法が思いつかなかった。

以下はコードとログである。
**ログ**

```
[Sub1] Used:1024 [KB] / Free: 512 [KB] (Largest: 512 [KB])
nitialization MediaRecorder, MediaPlayer and OutputMixer
recorder init
player init
mptask_exec() failure. -12
Attention: module[11][0] attention id[2]/code[18] (components/decoder/decoder_component.cpp L593)

[Main] Used:1408 [KB] / Free: 128 [KB] (Largest: 128 [KB])
recorder start
Attention: module[4][0] attention id[1]/code[6] (objects/media_recorder/audio_recorder_sink.cpp L84)

error! -116Attention!! Level 0x1 Code 0x6
```

**maincore.ino**

```
#include <MP.h>
#include <MediaRecorder.h>
#include <MediaPlayer.h>
#include <OutputMixer.h>
#include <MemoryUtil.h>

MediaRecorder *theRecorder;
MediaPlayer *thePlayer;
OutputMixer *theMixer;

/* Now suppot only mono channel*/

/* Select mic channel number */
const int mic_channel_num = 1;
//const int mic_channel_num = 2;

const int32_t s_buffer_size = 768 * mic_channel_num * sizeof(uint16_t);
uint8_t s_buffer[s_buffer_size];
bool ErrEnd = false;

const int subcore = 1;

struct Request {
  void *buffer;
  int  sample;
};

struct Result {
  void *buffer;
  int  sample;
};

/**
   @brief Audio attention callback

   When audio internal error occurc, this function will be called back.
*/

static void attention_callback(const ErrorAttentionParam *atprm)
{
  puts("Attention!");

  if (atprm->error_code >= AS_ATTENTION_CODE_WARNING)
  {
    ErrEnd = true;
  }
}

/**
   @brief Recorder done callback procedure

   @param [in] event        AsRecorderEvent type indicator
   @param [in] result       Result
   @param [in] sub_result   Sub result

   @return true on success, false otherwise
*/

static bool mediarecorder_event_callback(AsRecorderEvent event, uint32_t result, uint32_t sub_result)
{
  return true;
}

/**
   @brief Mixer done callback procedure

   @param [in] requester_dtq    MsgQueId type
   @param [in] reply_of         MsgType type
   @param [in,out] done_param   AsOutputMixDoneParam type pointer
*/
static void outputmixer_event_callback(MsgQueId requester_dtq,
                                      MsgType reply_of,
                                      AsOutputMixDoneParam *done_param)
{
  return;
}

/**
   @brief Mixer data send callback procedure

   @param [in] identifier   Device identifier
   @param [in] is_end       For normal request give false, for stop request give true
*/
static void outmixer_rendering_callback(int32_t identifier, bool is_end)
{
  AsRequestNextParam next;

  next.type = (!is_end) ? AsNextNormalRequest : AsNextStopResRequest;

  AS_RequestNextPlayerProcess(AS_PLAYER_ID_0, &next);

  return;
}

/**
   @brief Player done callback procedure

   @param [in] event        AsPlayerEvent type indicator
   @param [in] result       Result
   @param [in] sub_result   Sub result

   @return true on success, false otherwise
*/
static bool mediaplayer_event_callback(AsPlayerEvent event, uint32_t result, uint32_t sub_result)
{
  /* If result of "Play", restart recording (It should been stopped when "Play" requested) */
  return true;
}

/**
   @brief Player decode callback procedure

   @param [in] pcm_param    AsPcmDataParam type
*/
void mediaplayer_decode_callback(AsPcmDataParam pcm_param)
{
  /* You can imprement any audio signal process */

  /* Output and sound audio data */
  theMixer->sendData(OutputMixer0,
                     outmixer_rendering_callback,
                     pcm_param);
}

void setup()
{

 
  /* Launch SubCore */
  int ret = MP.begin(subcore);
  if (ret < 0) {
    printf("MP.begin error = %d\n", ret);
  }
  /* receive with non-blocking */
   MP.RecvTimeout(20);

  /* Initialize memory pools and message libs */
  Serial.println("Init memory Library");

  initMemoryPools();
  createStaticPools(MEM_LAYOUT_RECORDINGPLAYER);

  /* start audio system */
  Serial.println("Init Audio Library");

  theRecorder = MediaRecorder::getInstance();
  thePlayer = MediaPlayer::getInstance();
  theMixer  = OutputMixer::getInstance();

  theRecorder->begin();
  thePlayer->begin();

  puts("initialization MediaRecorder, MediaPlayer and OutputMixer");

  theMixer->activateBaseband();

  /* Create Objects */

  thePlayer->create(MediaPlayer::Player0, attention_callback);
  theMixer->create(attention_callback);

  /* Activate Objects. Set output device to Speakers/Headphones */

  theRecorder->activate(AS_SETRECDR_STS_INPUTDEVICE_MIC, mediarecorder_event_callback);
  thePlayer->activate(MediaPlayer::Player0, AS_SETPLAYER_OUTPUTDEVICE_SPHP, mediaplayer_event_callback);
  theMixer->activate(OutputMixer0, outputmixer_event_callback);

  usleep(100 * 1000);

  /*
     Initialize recorder to decode stereo wav stream with 48kHz sample rate
     Search for SRC filter in "/mnt/sd0/BIN" directory
  */
  uint8_t channel;
  switch (mic_channel_num) {
    case 1: channel = AS_CHANNEL_MONO;   break;
    case 2: channel = AS_CHANNEL_STEREO; break;
    case 4: channel = AS_CHANNEL_4CH;    break;
  }
  
  //const auto codec_path = "/mnt/spif/BIN";

  theRecorder->init(AS_CODECTYPE_LPCM, channel, AS_SAMPLINGRATE_16000, AS_BITLENGTH_16, 0);//サンプリングレートを変更したらどうにかなる？
  theRecorder->setMicGain(180);
  puts("recorder init");
  thePlayer->init(MediaPlayer::Player0, AS_CODECTYPE_WAV,AS_SAMPLINGRATE_16000, channel);
  puts("player init");

  /* Start Recorder */

  theMixer->setVolume(0, 0, 0);
  
  #if 1
    //memcheck
    int usedMem, freeMem, largestFreeMem;
  
    MP.GetMemoryInfo(usedMem, freeMem, largestFreeMem);
  
    MPLog("Used:%4d [KB] / Free:%4d [KB] (Largest:%4d [KB])\n",
          usedMem / 1024, freeMem / 1024, largestFreeMem / 1024);
  #endif 
}

typedef enum e_appState {
  StateReady = 0,
  StatePrepare,
  StateRun
} appState_t;

void loop()
{
  static appState_t state = StateReady;

  int8_t   sndid = 100; /* user-defined msgid */
  int8_t   rcvid = 0;
  int      read_size;
  int      ret;

  static Request  request;
  static Result*  result;
  
  switch (state) {
    case StateReady:
      {
      /* Start recording */
      theRecorder->start();
      puts("recorder start");
      state = StatePrepare;
      break;
      }
    case StatePrepare:
    {
      static int pre_cnt = 0;
      err_t err = theRecorder->readFrames(s_buffer, s_buffer_size, &read_size);

      if (err != 0) { printf("Error! %x ,%x , %d\n",err,request.buffer,request.sample); }

      if (read_size > 0)
      {
        request.buffer  = s_buffer;
        request.sample = read_size/ sizeof(uint16_t) / mic_channel_num;
        MP.Send(sndid, &request, subcore);

        if (pre_cnt < 2) {
          pre_cnt++;
          break;
        }

        /* Receive sound from SubCore */
        int ret = MP.Recv(&rcvid, &result, subcore);
        if (ret >= 0) {
          if (result->sample != 768) { break;}
          thePlayer->writeFrames(MediaPlayer::Player0, result->buffer, result->sample*2);
          pre_cnt++;
        } else {
          printf("error! %d", ret);
          exit(1);
        }
      } else {
        break;
      }

      if (pre_cnt > 10) {
        puts("player start");
        thePlayer->start(MediaPlayer::Player0, mediaplayer_decode_callback);
        pre_cnt = 0;
        state = StateRun;
      }
      break;
    }

    case StateRun:
    {
      err_t err = theRecorder->readFrames(s_buffer, s_buffer_size, &read_size);

      if (err != 0) {printf("Error! %x ,%x , %d\n",err,request.buffer,read_size);}
      if (read_size > 0)
      {
        request.buffer  = s_buffer;
        request.sample = read_size / sizeof(uint16_t) / mic_channel_num;
        MP.Send(sndid, &request, subcore);

        /* Receive sound from SubCore */
        ret = MP.Recv(&rcvid, &result, subcore);
        if (ret >= 0) {
          if (result->sample != 768) {break;}
          thePlayer->writeFrames(MediaPlayer::Player0,result->buffer, result->sample*2);
        } else {
          printf("error! %d", ret);
          exit(1);
        }
      } else {
        break;
      }
      break;
    }
    default:
    {
      puts("error!");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

**subcore.ino**

```
#include <MP.h>

#include "IIR.h"

/* Use CMSIS library */
#define ARM_MATH_CM4
#define __FPU_PRESENT 1U
#include <cmsis/arm_math.h>

/* channel number */
const int g_channel = 1;

IIRClass LPF;

/* Allocate the larger heap size than default */

USER_HEAP_SIZE(64 * 1024);

/* MultiCore definitions */

struct Request {
  void *buffer;
  int  sample;
};

struct Result {
  void *buffer;
  int  sample;
};

void setup()
{
  int ret = 0;

  /* Initialize MP library */
  ret = MP.begin();
  if (ret < 0) {
    errorLoop(2);
  }
  /* receive with non-blocking */
//  MP.RecvTimeout(MP_RECV_POLLING);
  MP.RecvTimeout(100000);
  LPF.begin(TYPE_LPF,g_channel,1000,sqrt(0.5));
    #if 1
    //memcheck
    int usedMem, freeMem, largestFreeMem;
  
    MP.GetMemoryInfo(usedMem, freeMem, largestFreeMem);
  
    MPLog("Used:%4d [KB] / Free:%4d [KB] (Largest:%4d [KB])\n",
          usedMem / 1024, freeMem / 1024, largestFreeMem / 1024);
  #endif 
}

#define RESULT_SIZE 4
void loop()
{
  int      ret;
  int8_t   sndid = 10; /* user-defined msgid */
  int8_t   rcvid;
  Request  *request;
  static Result result[RESULT_SIZE];

  static q15_t pDst[FRAMSIZE];
  static q15_t out_buffer[RESULT_SIZE][FRAMSIZE*g_channel];
  static int pos=0;

  /* Receive PCM captured buffer from MainCore */
  ret = MP.Recv(&rcvid, &request);
  if (ret >= 0) {
      LPF.put((q15_t*)request->buffer,request->sample);
  }else{
      puts("error!");
      return;
  }

  int cnt = 0;
  while (!LPF.empty(0)) {
    for (int i = 0; i < g_channel; i++) {
      cnt = LPF.get(pDst,i);
      /* support only mono channel */
      memcpy(&out_buffer[pos][0],pDst,cnt*2);
    }

    result[pos].buffer = MP.Virt2Phys(&out_buffer[pos][0]);
    result[pos].sample = cnt;

    ret = MP.Send(sndid, &result[pos],0);
    pos = (pos+1)%RESULT_SIZE;
    if (ret < 0) {
      errorLoop(1);
    }
  }
}

void errorLoop(int num)
{
  int i;

  while (1) {
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      ledOn(LED0);
      delay(300);
      ledOff(LED0);
      delay(300);
    }
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

自分が実行したところ、特にノイズにはなりませんでした。

ただ、このエラーは、確かに出ますね。

WARNING: Insufficient buffer area.
Error! 8 ,d04d8b0 , 1536

でも、このエラー出ても動作するようです。
WARNING なので、警告程度なのでしょうか。

Comment: 私の環境でもう一度試してみたのですが、激しくノイズが乗りつつも「あ-」と声を入れると「あー…ぁー……ー」のようにエコーがかかった音声が出力されました。
参考にしたいため、マイクがどのように接続されているか教えていただけませんか？

Comment: 参考になるかわからないのですが、自分は、ソニーさんの拡張ボードではなく、こちらを使っています。

PDA01 SPRESENSE用機能拡張ボード
https://www.switch-science.com/catalog/5687/

これだとAudio-Inの汎用マイクが使えたので。　ちなみに、通常の記録ではノイズが乗らないのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます！そんな拡張ボードがあるんですねぇ…知らなかった。

通常の記録ではノイズが乗らないのか->
スケッチサンプル"Recorder"では正常に動作し、録音できております。エラーから読み取れる直接の原因は、"サブコアにDSPモジュールがロードできなかった"ことで、最近のIDEのアップデートで使用できるメモリ量を変更できるようになったことが原因かも…と予想できてきました

Comment: 通常の記録では問題ないのですね。となるとマイク周辺のHW起因の問題ではないのでしょうね。あまり力になれずすみません。ちなみにSDK2.00では、メモリサイズ変更部分に問題がありそうでした。

Comment: 1点、思い出しました。スピーカをお使いですか？スピーカの場合、マイクと近い位置にあると、ハウリングを起こしてしまうようです。なので、自分はヘッドフォンを使いました。誰かハウリング除去のライブラリ作ってくれませんかねえ。

Comment: むむむぅ…ヘッドホンでも試してみたんですが…結果はかわらず…。ですが、とりあえず別のサンプルコードの"voice effector"目的が達成できそうです！処理速度の問題が現れないことと、sonyのサポーターさんがこの質問をも見つけてもらえることを祈りつつ未解決のまま放置いたします。なんども確認してくださってありがとうございました！！